# lm command does not show correct module

Tags: windbg, dllimport

I use WinDbg to analyze Adobe Acrobat Reader, `AcroRd32.exe`. I want to see what modules (the .dll modules that in the same directory with `AcroRd32.exe`) that `AcroRd.exe` loaded.

I use WinDbg monitoring to open a PDF file, then use `lm` command to show loaded modules. However, there is no module (.DLL) that has same directory as `AcroRd32.exe`.

Does that mean `AcroRd32.exe` didn't use these DLLs? To verify my assumption， I deleted all DLL files that are in the same directory as `AcroRd32.exe`. Then `AcroRd32.exe` cannot start normally. It means that these DLLs are necessary for `AcroRd32.exe`. But Why WinDbg's `lm` command didn't show these DLL modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acrobat Reader starts another instance of itself. You need to debug the second instance to see the modules being loaded:

```
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2b:
77e9db9b cc              int     3
0:000> .childdbg 1
Processes created by the current process will be debugged    
0:000> sxe cpr
0:000> g
[...]
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00c20000 00e45000   AcroRd32.exe
```

At this point, the second instance is going to be started.

```
1:010> g
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2b:
77e9db9b cc              int     3
1:010> g
```

If you break when Acrobat Reader has loaded, you'll see:

```
1:010> |0s
0:000> lmf
[...]
No Adobe Acrobat Reader DLLs
[...]
0:000> |1s
1:010> lmf
[...]
56910000 56961000   sqlite   C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\sqlite.dll
56970000 569a4000   AXE8SharedExpat C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AXE8SharedExpat.dll
569b0000 56a9c000   ACE      C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\ACE.dll
56aa0000 56d78000   CoolType C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\CoolType.dll
56d80000 56d9e000   BIB      C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\BIB.dll
56da0000 572c2000   AGM      C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AGM.dll
[...]
```

The first instance does not have DLLs loaded from Adobe Acrobat's directory but the second one has.

Comment: thanks for for your helpful answer!! Your answer helped me a lot. I have an another problem, if you have time, can you help me solve it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46602166/windbg-how-to-control-mutil-process-debugging

Comment: If you think the answer is correct, please check the checkmark at the answer so that others know the problem is solved. I'll have a look at your new question.